# Understanding of the definition of an algebra over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

I'm given the following definitions of an $A-$algebra over a commutative ring with 1 and ring extension: an $A-$algebra $B$ is a ring $B$ together with a given ring homomorphism $\phi: A\rightarrow B$. If $A\subset B$, then $B$ is called an extension ring of $A$. A few questions arise:

1. How does one know what the map $\phi$ is? To be specific, the author of the book I'm using states that $k[x^2]\subset k[x]$ is an (integral) extension. By the above definition it means in particular that $k[x]$ is a $k[x^2]-$algebra, so it is assumed that there is a homomorphism of rings $\phi: k[x^2]\rightarrow k[x]$. How am I supposed to understand the formula by which this $\phi$ is defined?
2. I read somewhere that often $\phi$ is the inclusion map. What are simple examples when it is not?

Comment: Work through the def with simple examples. $\mathbb C$ is an $\mathbb R$-algebra. If you work through the def with this example in mind things will be more clear.

Comment: Note that this is not the most common definition of an $A$-algebra. The usual definition requires that the image of $\phi$ be a subset of the center of $B$. By this definition, $\mathbb H$ is a $\mathbb C$-algebra.

Comment: @rschwieb: this definition came from a book on commutative algebra, where all rings are assumed to be commutative (and with 1). So $B$ in the question is also assumed to be commutative, I forgot to mention this.

Comment: @Cary OK, that's good to know :) Yes, that would make the two definitions match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A\subset B$, then $B$ is an $A$-algebra via the inclusion map. In particular, that's what the map in your question (1) is. That is, $\phi: a\mapsto a$. As a point of language, if there is an "obvious" choice of $\phi$ (e.g. an inclusion map) and no $\phi$ is explicitly specified, then the "obvious" choice is meant. (If this strikes you as bad writing practice, I'd agree - and I've heard of examples where papers were found to contain errors because they conflated multiple "obvious" choices of $\phi$. But this is nonetheless common practice.)

For question (2), you ask when $\phi$ is *not* the inclusion map. Well, what if there **is no** inclusion map at all? For example, any ring $R$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra via the homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow R$ generated by $\phi(1_\mathbb{Z})=1_R$; but many rings don't contain $\mathbb{Z}$, even up to isomorphism (take $R=\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$, e.g.).

Even when there is an embedding, we don't need to take it as our $\phi$! For example, look at the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $R$ is an $R$-module via the identity map; but also via other maps. Consider e.g. the ring homomorphism $f: R\rightarrow R$ generated by $f(x)=x^2$. This gives $R$ a different algebra structure. I'm not an algebraist, but my understanding is that while such "unnatural" algebra structures tend to be *individually* not as interesting, the *set of all* ways of viewing $S$ as an $R$-algebra is quite an interesting object, and the "unnatural" algebra structures play important roles in it.

Comment: Note one important takeaway here: there will in general be many non-equivalent ways of viewing $S$ as an $R$-algebra.